# Need to install xampp 1.8.2 to different folder in ubuntu

Tags: web, xampp

I have ubuntu and I have **xampp 1.7.7** installed in */opt/lampp* and I want to install **xampp 1.8.2** in another folder because I need php 5.4 for a project hosted on google app engine

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this 
http://bitnami.com/stack/lamp 
I have installed in different folder and then I stopped xampp and start it whenever I need it